# If the quantity $P=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} $ is conserved for different combinations of the two variables, is the quantity $Q=a+b$ conserved as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

If the quantity $P=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} $ must always be the same for different combinations of the values of the two variables, then is it correct to state that the quantity $Q=a+b$ is also conserved?

Answer (score 6):

No. For example, take the pairs $(a, b)=(1,1)$ and $(a,b)=(2,\frac 2 3)$. Both pairs satisfy $P=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=2$, but for the first pair $Q=1+1=2$ while for the second pair, $Q=2+\frac 2 3=\frac 8 3$.

Answer (score 2):

No, suppose that it is conserved. Then, $$ab=\frac{Q}{P}$$
is also conserved. But, in that case, $a$ and $b$ are also fixed, being the roots of $$x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$$
i.e. $$x^2-Qx+\frac{Q}{P}=0$$

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Let the quantity

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{ab}=X$$

Then

$$a+b=abX$$

If $a+b$ is to be conserved, then we must have

$$a+b=abX:=-B\Rightarrow ab=\frac{-B}{X}:=C$$

And so $ab$ is also conserved.

Thus $a$ and $b$ are roots of the quadratic equation

$$x^2+Bx+C=0$$

where $B$ and $C$ are fixed constants.
Thus $a$ and $b$ are fixed numbers and not variable. We have a contradiction.